# `Cannot find module '../scripts/ios'` trying to run iOS simulator after copying project directory

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I created a React Native project with `create-react-native-app projname`. I built an app and ran in the sim with `npm run ios`. Then I copied the directory with `cp -r projname /some/other/path/projname`, cd'd into the new path, and tried `npm run ios` again.

Got this error:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/ios'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:27:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alecz/Developer/gmna/server/no80/node_modules/.bin/react-native-scripts:18:79)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! no80@0.1.0 ios: `react-native-scripts ios`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the no80@0.1.0 ios script.
```

Odd because I don't see `scripts` in the original dir's parent.

This is a problem when cloning my app from git (or cloning someone else's repo). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out as I was asking... Had to `rm node_modules` then `npm install` in the new dir. No idea why.